# SQL field empty needs to be NULL

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a SQL through a framework which stores it in the database only he should make the field ’name’ NULL but instead he makes the field empty and not NULL. Now I have a SQL query that collects the data from the database where ‘name’ is NULL but because the field is empty and not NULL  he does display the field ‘name’. So the problem is the field ‘name’ must be NULL and not empty. I already have in my database selected empty and default value NULL. Can somebody help me with my problem?

Comment: SQL is not a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `UPDATE` the field using `NULLIF(name,'')`

`NULLIF` returns null if the expressions match, ie if name is blank, it returns NULL. If the expression's don't match it returns the first expression, in this case, name.

```
UPDATE table_name
 SET name = NULLIF(name,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE the field within your client.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value 
WHERE some_column= NULL